# How to quantify if model predictions are close with expected values in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, goodness-of-fit

I have two sets of data where X are the observed and Y the expected values. I am trying to quantify the goodness of fit with Python. It is very common for people to calculate [image] of the datasets and decide which is better based on these values, which is wrong. I want values that help me decide which dataset has observed values close to the expected values. I tried [image] tests with Python but are there any other tests that can help in deciding which has the best fit.

**Code**

```
from scipy.stats import chisquare
import numpy as np

x1 = np.array([97.83, 95.06, 92.54, 97.69, 93.76, 93.36, 93.37, 99.29, 101.57, 
        97.88, 98.71, 75.31, 72.52, 67.75, 77.97, 78.42, 72.62, 82.29, 90.26, 76.32, 78.78, 79.96])
y1 = np.array([90.90, 90.50, 89.50, 92.90, 91.20, 91.70, 91.40, 94.20, 96.80,
        93.30, 94.40, 70.20, 71.20, 68.40, 74.20, 74.60, 72.00, 77.80, 83.00, 73.50, 76.70, 82.60])


x2 = ([92.14, 91.44, 91.31, 93.26, 93.26, 91.65, 92.41, 93.47, 97.12, 101.46, 
        94.99, 98.08, 69.33, 69.63, 68.45, 72.62, 71.17, 80.54, 90.42, 74.25, 79.60, 80.77])
y2 = ([90.90, 90.50, 89.50, 92.90, 93.00, 91.20, 91.70, 91.40, 94.20, 96.80, 93.30, 
        94.40, 70.20, 71.20, 68.40, 74.20, 72.00, 77.80, 83.00, 73.50, 76.70, 82.60])

print chisquare(x1, y1)
print chisquare(x2, y2)
```

**Update**

```
from scipy.stats import chisquare
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

x1 = np.array([97.83, 95.06, 92.54, 97.69, 93.76, 93.36, 93.37, 99.29, 101.57, 
        97.88, 98.71, 75.31, 72.52, 67.75, 77.97, 78.42, 72.62, 82.29, 90.26, 76.32, 78.78, 79.96])
y1 = np.array([90.90, 90.50, 89.50, 92.90, 91.20, 91.70, 91.40, 94.20, 96.80,
        93.30, 94.40, 70.20, 71.20, 68.40, 74.20, 74.60, 72.00, 77.80, 83.00, 73.50, 76.70, 82.60])


x2 = ([92.14, 91.44, 91.31, 93.26, 93.26, 91.65, 92.41, 93.47, 97.12, 101.46, 
        94.99, 98.08, 69.33, 69.63, 68.45, 72.62, 71.17, 80.54, 90.42, 74.25, 79.60, 80.77])
y2 = ([90.90, 90.50, 89.50, 92.90, 93.00, 91.20, 91.70, 91.40, 94.20, 96.80, 93.30, 
        94.40, 70.20, 71.20, 68.40, 74.20, 72.00, 77.80, 83.00, 73.50, 76.70, 82.60])


print "Scikit R2, 1:", r2_score(y1, x1)
print "Scikit R2, 2:", r2_score(y2, x2)


slope1, intercept1, r_value1, p_value1, std_err1 = stats.linregress(y1,x1)
slope2, intercept2, r_value2, p_value2, std_err2 = stats.linregress(y2,x2)


print "Stats R2, 1:", r_value1**2
print "Stats R2, 2", r_value2**2
```

With the updated code the following output is obtained:

```
Scikit R2, 1: 0.820091025592
Scikit R2, 2: 0.928643087517
Stats R2, 1: 0.958813342741
Stats R2, 2 0.965013525387
```

Why do R2 values obtained from scikit and scipy differ?

Comment: Look up http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html

Comment: Are R2 values determined with Scikit different from the usual R2 values, because their values are different. Theoretically how different are they?

Answer (score 2):

The two functions you list ([`scipy.stats.linregress`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) and [`sklearn.metrics.r2_score`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html)) do different things.

#### sklearn.metrics.r2_score

`sklearn.metrics.r2_score` does what you are looking for: it takes two sets of data, and computes the `R^2` (coefficient of determination) between those two sets. From the docs:

> sklearn.metrics.**r2_score**(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None, multioutput=None)
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> **y_true** : array-like of shape = (n_samples) or (n_samples, n_outputs)
>
> Ground truth (correct) target values.
>
> **y_pred** : array-like of shape = (n_samples) or (n_samples, n_outputs)
>
> Estimated target values.

So, your observed data (`x1,x2`) are your `y_true`, and your expected values (`y1,y2`) are your `y_pred`. So, this is the correct way to call it:

```
r2_score(x1, y1)
```

#### scipy.stats.linregress

`scipy.stats.linregress` does not do what you are looking for. Its purpose is to perform a linear regression and find a fit to two sets of data (not a set of data and its predicted values). The `r_value` it returns (which you can square to get  `R^2`, is the correlation coefficient between the `y` value you feed it and the predicted values from the regression (fitting) it performs. Since you already know your predicted values, this is not the function you are looking for.